# How to insert data into SQL Server database using php, jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql, sql-server, ajax

I'm new to SQL Server. I need to insert data into the database using php, jQuery, ajax and T-SQL. I'm using `sqlsrv` library, when I'm running this code in mysql it's working properly, but when I'm changing mysql to SQL Server, it's not working properly, and showing some array to string problem. How can I change mysql code to SQL Server and how to retrieve data using `sqlsrv`?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email'])  && isset($_POST['event1']))
    {
        // include Database connection file 
        include("db_connection.php");

        // get values 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $event1 = $_POST['event1'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO demo(first_name, last_name, email, event1) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$event1')";
        if (!$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)) 
        {
            exit(sqlsrv_errors());
        }
        echo "1 Record Added!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This looks like a good place for you to start http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

Comment: `sqlsrv_errors()` returns an array, `exit()` takes a string parameter... That's probably where your *array to string* error is coming from; meaning your query failed. Change it to `exit(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));` and that should give you some information as to why your query isn't working.

Comment: Can you update the question with the `db_connection.php` file contents ?

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<title>h26t5hr5ge8dxbf6dit034hd8rt4fd</title>
<body>
<p>
    function save_data()
    {
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var email=$("#email").val();
        var phone=$("#phone").val();
        var user_id=$("#user_id").val();
        var passwd=$("#passwd").val();

            $.ajax({
            url :'faculty-db.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'html',
            data:{
                'action':'save',
                'name':name,
                'email':email,
                'phone':phone,
                'user_id':user_id,
                'passwd':passwd
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#my_data').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" 

alt="Loading...">');
                //$('#btn_save').prop("disabled", true);
            },
            async: false,
            success  :function(data){
                $('#my_data').html(data);
                $('#myform')[0].reset();
                //$('#btn_save').prop("disabled", false);
                show_data();
            }
        }).responseText;
    }

    function show_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url :'faculty-db.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'html',
            data :{'action':'show'},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#my_data').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" 

alt="Loading...">');
            },
            async: false,
            success  :function(data){
                $('#my_data').html(data);
            }
        }).responseText;
    }

    function edit_data(faculty_id)
    {
        myWindow = window.open("faculty-edit.php?

faculty_id="+faculty_id, "myWindow", "width=870,height=530");
        //alert(subject_id);
    }

    function delete_data(faculty_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url :'faculty-db.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'html',
            data :{
                'action':'del',
                'faculty_id':faculty_id
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#my_data').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" 

alt="Loading...">');
            },
            async: false,
            success  :function(data){
                $('#my_data').html(data);

                show_data();
            }
        }).responseText;
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
       // show_data();
    });
</p>

<p>
include_once("connection-pdo.php");

$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
switch($action) {

    case 'save':
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
        $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
        $passwd = $_REQUEST['passwd'];

        echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `faculty_master`

(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`user_id`,`password`) VALUE

('$name','$email','$phone','$user_id','$passwd')";
        $query = $pdoconn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        break;

    case 'show':
        $html='';
        $html.='<'table>
            <'tr>
                <'th>ID</th>
                <'th>NAME</th>
                <'th>EMAIL</th>
                <'th>PHONE</th>
                <'th>USER ID</th>
                <'th>PASSWORD</th>
                <'th>EDIT</th>
                <'th>DELETE</th>';


        $sql = "SELECT 

faculty_id,`name`,`email`,`phone`,`user_id`,`password` FROM 

`faculty_master` WHERE del_flag=0";
        $query  = $pdoconn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $arr_faculty = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $slno=1;
        foreach($arr_faculty as $val) {
            $name = $val['name'];
            $email = $val['email'];
            $phone = $val['phone'];
            $user_id = $val['user_id'];
            $passwd = $val['password'];


            $html .= '<'/tr>
                       <'tr>
                             <'td>'.$slno.'</td>
                             <'td>'.$name.'</td>
                             <'td>'.$email.'</td>
                             <'td>'.$phone.'</td>
                             <'td>'.$user_id.'</td>
                             <'td>'.$passwd.'</td>
                             <'td> <img src="images/edit.png" 

style="cursor: pointer"  onclick="edit_data('.$val

['faculty_id'].')"></td>
                             <'td> <img src="images/delete.png" 

style="cursor: pointer" onclick="delete_data('.$val

['faculty_id'].')"></td>
                       <'/tr>';

            $slno++;

        }

        $html.='<'/table>';
        echo $html;
        break;

    case 'del':
        $faculty_id=$_REQUEST['faculty_id'];
        $sql ="UPDATE `faculty_master` SET `del_flag`=1 WHERE 

`faculty_id`=$faculty_id";
        $query  = $pdoconn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        break;

    case 'update':

        $faculty_id=$_REQUEST['faculty_id'];
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
        $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
        $passwd=$_REQUEST['passwd'];

        $sql ="UPDATE `faculty_master` SET 

`name`='$name',`email`='$email',`phone`='$phone',`user_id`='$user_id',`

password`='$passwd' WHERE `faculty_id`=$faculty_id";
        $query  = $pdoconn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        if($query)
            echo 'EDITED SUCCESSFULLY';
        else
            echo 'ERROR WHILE EDITING...';
        break;

}
?>
</p>

<p>
include_once("connection-pdo.php");
$faculty_id=$_REQUEST['faculty_id'];
$sql = "SELECT `name`,`email`,`phone`,`user_id`,`password` FROM 

`faculty_master` WHERE del_flag=0  AND faculty_id=$faculty_id";
$query  = $pdoconn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$arr_faculty = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$name = $arr_faculty[0]['name'];
$email = $arr_faculty[0]['email'];
$phone = $arr_faculty[0]['phone'];
$user_id = $arr_faculty[0]['user_id'd];
$passwd = $arr_faculty[0]['password'];
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a description how this code works. I think you must add script and php tags